# How to return connection to connection pool in cache intersystems?

Tags: java, jdbc, intersystems-cache

in my java project I'm using Cache JDBC-driver for DB connection.
So, to create connection pool I use:

```
public CacheConnectionPoolDataSource pds = null;
...
   public final void Connect() {
    try {
        pds = new CacheConnectionPoolDataSource();
        pds.restartConnectionPool();
        pds.setMaxPoolSize(7);
        pds.setURL("jdbc:Cache://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + namespase);
        pds.setUser(dblogin);
        pds.setPassword(dbpassword);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

To get connection I use:

```
static public Connection GetConnection() {
    Connection cn = null;
    try {
        cn = pds.getConnection();
        cn.setAutoCommit(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        if (cn == null) {
            try {
                GetInstance().Connect();
                cn = pds.getConnection();
                cn.setAutoCommit(true);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
    return cn;
}
```

After making query like this:

```
ResultSet result = Database.GetInstance().Query(query);
```

I use "FreeResultSet(result);":

```
static public void FreeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    try {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            statement = resultSet.getStatement();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        if (statement != null) {
            connection = statement.getConnection();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            resultSet.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    Database.FreeStatement(statement);
    Database.FreeConnection(connection);
}

static public void FreeConnection(Connection con) {
    try {
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

static public void FreeStatement(Statement st) {
    try {
        if (st != null) {
            st.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It works almost fine.. But when I'm using many queries at the same time, there appear too many coonections (up to 25) (bigger than 7 I declaired in "pds.setMaxPoolSize(7);"), and in Cache Control Panel in "License Usage by User" its growing to 25 and my application cannot get any coonections, because 1 Cache license gives me only 25 max connections.

So.. What am I doing wrong?)

Comment: You are probably calling `Connect()` more than once, and therefor have more than one instance of the connection pool. You also might fail to close the connection when an exception other than `SQLException` occurs. Check your code carefully for resource leaks.